# Is anybody experiencing slowness when using Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, performance

Is anybody experiencing extreme slowness when using Visual Studio 2008?  I have a fairly beefy machine so I don't think hardware is the issue, and I didn't have these issues with 2005.  Basically everything that I do is slow, from opening a new project, to opening code, to saving files.  All of my Windows Updates are up, I have VS2008 SP1 installed, and I even tried disabling the virus protection.

Comment: Why would you disable virus protection? o.O It could be a virus slowing things down..

Can you post your computers spec? I don't believe 'beefy' is much of a description. 64k was beefy once.

Comment: Do you you have any addins installed?

Comment: You can get a lot of tips by Googling "speed up visual studio 2008"

Comment: @Lou: I add some issues some time ago with virus protections like that: every time my program was reading a directory , it was involving the virus protection program (which scan every file in the directory before I access them .. !!) thus slowing down my own program ... Disabling the virus protection make my program much more reactive.

Comment: @Lou: I disabled virus protection to see if that was causing the slowness.  I have a Core 2 Quad @2.4 GHz, 2 gigs of ram.

Comment: @Gulzar, I have no addins installed.

Comment: Just wondering why somebody would vote to close this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to fix my immediate issue (copied and pasted from the link provided by Gulzar):

As an update, I found an even better fix so you dont' have to lose any functionality in VS 2008.  This also drastically improved performance (response time) for me in SQL server management Studio.

In Internet Explorer 7...

Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Security Node->Uncheck 'Check for publisher's certificate revocation*'

Once I did this, like magic, VS 2008 works great even with 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process'  checked and SQL Server Management Studio's response time was almost immediate.

It is a good day!

My theory is the corporate network I am in is blocking certain ports (out of my control), and thus certain 'behind the scenes' requests are timing out, causing the delays.

- Robbie

Answer (score 2):

Try loading Visual Studio in safe mode to load the default environment with  [/safemode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(VS.80).aspx) switch.

You might also want to try some of the answers here:

[Visual Studio 2008 PAINFULLY SLOW!!](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/bc778e26-9156-4924-a9ca-a57ef8ff6bcc/)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes it is slow.**

I have a very fast Intel E8500 machine (2x3.16ghz) with 4gigs of RAM and Visual Studio 2008 IS SLOW.

Opening a dialog is slow, creating a new project is slow, you have to wait a few seconds after the dialogs.

NOT everytime though, because once you load these dialogs in memory, they are faster the second time.

But it's still too slow, much too slow.

Comment: Did you experience the same slowness with 2005?

Comment: Yes. But 2008 is slightly faster. On my laptop I made it go faster because I have only C++. Don't install what you won't use, I noticed  a speed improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Disk speed can cause this problem and also add-ins like resharper

Comment: Resharper is a massive performance drain - even with the new release.

Comment: I don't have resharper or any other addins.

Answer (score 0):

Not everyone has the problem you're seeing. Try to disable add-ins, as has been suggested, then also monitor your computer to get an idea of what's going on. Is there extra disk I/O? A lot of page faults? What?

Comment: I have no add-ins.  Where can I monitor the disk I/O and page faults?

Comment: On Windows XP and below, use Administrative Tools->Performance. On Vista and above, I suggest starting with Task Manager, then clicking the Resource Monitor button.

Answer (score 0):

Empty your recycle bin.  Turn off 'wrap text' in the output window.

Comment: May I ask what emptying the recycle bin would accomplish?